# Bayesian Regression - Overview

Tags: regression, bayesian, references

Does anyone know a comprehensive, well-written and recent **book** / collection of articles about **Bayesian regression** and **variable selection**?

The topics I am particularly interested in are:

- constraints of categorical variables
- ordinal bayesian regression
- interaction effects (including hierarchical models incorporating lower and higher order effects)
- generalised Bayesian regression
- cross-validation techniques
- any other topics dealt with in recent research

I am mainly interested in the mathematical background of these methods.

Answer (score 2):

Bayesian regression is handled in pretty much *every Bayesian textbook* see e.g.

- [Gelman et al.'s Bayesian Data Analysis](https://amzn.to/2WCtztU)
- [Hoff's A First Course in Bayesian Statistical Methods](https://amzn.to/2D4Aljq)
- [Rossi's and Allenby's Bayesian Statistics and Marketing](https://amzn.to/2t1f1X8)
- [Koop's Bayesian Econometrics](https://amzn.to/2sYG5GK)
- [Greenberg's Introduction to Bayesian Econometrics](https://amzn.to/2t4fqIE)

and of course the reference

- [Zellner's An introduction to Bayesian methods in econometrics](https://amzn.to/2t2M6lR)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. U have already looked into Gelman et al. But I did not find it detailed enough.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to *Xi'an*'s answer, since you mention many regression models etc., the [*Data Analysis Using Regression and Multilevel/Hierarchical Models*](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/arm/) book by Gelman & Hill is also worth mentioning. It focuses on regression models in general, but with strong emphasis on Bayesian approach.